# ES6 Classes: Is this a proof for prototype extending another one?

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, prototype, ecmascript-6

While playing around with Babel.js and doing some extending with classes I realized something that might be a good way to differentiate common class inheritance (Java, C#...) and prototype (I don't really say class here somehow) inheritance.

**Given the following to base-class:**

```
class Menu {

  constructor(){}

  render(){
    this.addObjectsToStage();
  }

  addObjectsToStage() {
    var objects = this.objects.getAllObjects();
    for (var category in objects) {
      if (objects.hasOwnProperty(category)) {
        for (var type in objects[category]) {
          if (objects[category].hasOwnProperty(type))
            this.stage.addChild(objects[category][type]);
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

**And its subclass:**

```
class MainMenu extends Menu{

  constructor(stage, options) {
    super();
    this.stage = stage;
    this.objects = new MenuObjects(options);
  }
}
```

Now what I want to point out is that the super-class **Menu** is calling a property this.**objects**.getAllObjects() (*in function "addObjectsToStage"*).

In a "common" object orientated language you wouldn't be able to access a property which is just defined when an instance of a sub-class is being created. So this, in my opinion, is a significant sign for a difference in inheritance styles.

So what I'd like to know now is if I'm pretty right or dead wrong!

Comment: This is a bit of a meta thought so I'm writing a comment not an answer but for many good reasons, the current general trend is away from complex inheritance chains and towards composition. You can do many complicated things. That doesn't mean you should do them. In fact, you shouldn't (in my opinion of course).

Comment: You can do this, but you shouldn't. It won't work if you have a Menu instance which is not a MainMenu instance. In case there won't be any such instance, merge both constructors into a single one.

Comment: AT Cymen yea I like a healthy mix of trivial inheritance and composition. @Oriol what exactly do you mean by merging the CTORs ? Can you give me an example?

Comment: @xetra11 I mean get rid of `Menu` and define its methods in `MainMenu`: https://jsfiddle.net/5pzzbaft/

Comment: @Oriol Thats what I had before. I also have Optionsmenu which has OptionObjects. I dont want to repeat code for every "class" and therefore I want a Menu Class which has a render and a addObjectsToStage method. That way I can inherit every XMenu from Menu

Comment: You are doing yourself a disservice by thinking of it as _inheriting from classes_; despite the existence of the keyword, there are no classes in JavaScript. As you have it written, `Menu` creates an incomplete object; what is your question?

Comment: if there's "no classes in JavaScript", what do you call the "stuff" that the "keyword" creates?

Comment: @Mathletics thats exactly what Im talking about. I come from OOP and have a big struggle NOT to use inheritance here.

Comment: @dandavis Well it creates a prototype doesnt it?

Comment: @dandavis a function? People were already doing "fake classes" with constructor functions; `class` is just syntactic sugar for the same. It doesn't do anything new under the hood. It's still just a function that returns an object.

Comment: Well Babel.js' Helper creates a constructor function and a prototype which can be used as template for other instances. Kinda like a class template but surely not the same due the lack of polymorphy etc. It's prototyping all over

Comment: @Mathletics: i'm just struggling to figure out how that "function" isn't described by the first sentence of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(computer_programming) just because something isn't exactly like something else doesn't mean it's not something. seem like all those trees are blocking your view of the forest... ;)

Comment: @dandavis well youre kinda right but since the class in the common sense of programming has been forged by Java, C# and other big OOP languages theres more details  for a class definition and surely there is a difference to a prototype.

Comment: @dandavis in classical languages, you have an actual `Class` entity which is used to create instances. In JavaScript, your "class" is actually an _instance_ of a _function_ and can be invoked, have properties attached to it, etc. It's just another object, literally an `Object`. Method delegation is done on the prototype chain, not via class inheritance, even with the new keywords.

Comment: @dandavis if you don't see the value of being specific and deliberate in the way you describe computer science, I guess I can't help you.

Comment: VB6's classes weren't the same as PHPs or Python's but only javascript gets beat up about it for some reason, and that irks me. sorry to get off topic.... functions are objects too you know, and maybe that overlap in JS grinds people the wrong way. thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Im not good in the class inheritance in language like java or c#. But your example will work in javascript. But as said in the comment, it will only work if the Menu instance is a MainMenu instance.

I see many java devs comming in javascript and dont understand the freedom of javascrpit. They need and want tools that tell them if what they write work or not. That's why we see more and more sub-language build on top of javascript to have a "class inheritance" feeling. But that's not the way javascript work. So they better learn and read about closure, function scope and also prototyping. Javascrpit is really simple and it force you to write good and logic code.

So the answer for me is : yes your pretty right. This is a significsnt sign of the difference between class and prototypal inheritance.

Comment: i somewhat agree, but this isn't a good answer according to SO

Comment: do you have some tips how to ensure stability if I let a class inherit from Menu which does not has the needed *object* property?  any best practises?

Comment: I can recomend you to test if the getAllObjects method exist, then execute the code else do nothing. You will have your code clear and ready to handle all the cases.

Comment: You also probably want to test if `this.object` exist before testing if .getAllObjects() exist.

Comment: I'm up to write an InheritanceHelper Class which will validate as generic as possible if all dafety rules are met. Sadly I still have to add this method per hand for every subclass property. Im trying to figure out how to make it more automatic and post the solution here.

Comment: @xetra11 Sounds great. Comme back here to give us some example.